# Retrofit2 - Upload photo 500 Internal Server error

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data, multipart

I want to upload a photo using Retrofit2, but I can't get rid of 500 Internal Server error. I also get the message "reduce of empty array with no initial value". When I retrieve the uploaded photos from the server, the photo is not there. I'm using Charles Web Debugging Proxy tool to check the response.

```
public static void postPhoto(String participantId, String photoPath) {
        try {
            File photo = new File(photoPath);
            ApiEndpoints api = ApiProvider.getInstance().getApiInstance();
            RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), photo);
            MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", photo.getName(), reqFile);
            Call<ResponseBody> call = api.uploadPhoto(participantId, body);
            call.execute();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

API endpoint

```
@Multipart
@POST("participant/{id}/image")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadPhoto(@Path("id") String id, @Part MultipartBody.Part image);
```

Comment: Is your own server?

Comment: have You tested in postman @blavi

Comment: @FlorescuGeorgeCatalin no, it's not mine.@jagapathi Yes, and I receive the same error. Now I see that it might not be an issue with how I create the retrofit2 call.